# hibernate+spring get max id in range

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hsqldb

How to get object with max id using hibernate + spring. I just need proper query for that. This is what i have tried.

```
Student s = new Student();

DetachedCriteria maxId = DetachedCriteria maxId = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.max("id"));

s = (Student) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Student.class)
        .add(Restrictions.between("id", 30000, 40000))
        .add(Property.forName("id").eq(maxId)).uniqueResult();
System.out.println(s.getId());
return s;
```

I also need result in range, its important condition. For example i want student in id range from 30000 to 40000. How can i achieve that?

i have also playing with this piece of code

```
s = (Student) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
          .createCriteria(Student.class).add(Restrictions.between("id", 30000,
          40000)).uniqueResult();
```

Just to mention that result is not supposed to be a list its supposed to be a unique result.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
   List<Student> results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                           .createCriteria(Student.class)
                           .setProjection(Projections.max("id"))
                           .add(Restrictions.between("id", 30000, 40000)).list();

   if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
       s = results.get(0);
   }
   else {
       // not found
   }
```

Comment: i haven't tested it, thanks for trying to help out, i have solved this problem, you can checkout my answer to this question.

Comment: It's the same code for the query, but I'm returning a student instead an int. Be careful with uniqueResult, this would raise an exception when query returns more than one result.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution, i managed to figure it out by myself:

```
int maxId = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Student.class)
                .add(Restrictions.between("id", 30000, 40000))
                .setProjection(Projections.max("id")).uniqueResult();
        s.setId(maxId);
```